# ghc failed to compile a sanity check

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, haskell-stack

I've recently been trying to use haskell-stack, but whenever i try to do stack setup i get

> The GHC located at
>   /home/piotrek/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc failed to
>   compile a sanity check. Please see:
>
> ```
> http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/
> ```
>
> for more information. Exception was: Running
>   /home/piotrek/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc
>   /tmp/stack-sanity-check3118/Main.hs -no-user-package-db in directory
>   /tmp/stack-sanity-check3118/ exited with ExitFailure 1
>
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             (
>   /tmp/stack-sanity-check3118/Main.hs,
>   /tmp/stack-sanity-check3118/Main.o ) Linking
>   /tmp/stack-sanity-check3118/Main ...
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/stack-sanity-check3118/Main.o: relocation
>   R_X86_64_32S against symbol `stg_bh_upd_frame_info' can not be used
>   when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

and many other messages like the last one about relocation.
I use ubuntu 16.10, installed stack by apt-get.

Comment: You'll find a lot of info related to this [on stack/issues](https://www.google.de/search?q=site%3Agithub.com%2Fcommercialhaskell%2Fstack%2Fissues+fpic). One thing that should work is using a nightly resolver / ghc-8.0.2.

Comment: It seems that this is a strange bug caused by GHC/GCC/linking.. or so the [stack faq](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/faq.md) claims, pointing to [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12759) trac ticket, but that ticket claims it was fixed in 8.0! Either it was not fixed or it is only stack that still somehow has the bug - you'll need to find a version of GHC working on your machine and point stack to that.

Comment: I'm running into this problem and can't seem to find a fix. For me it's ghc-8.4.4.